# Why does my fitted encoder not work after I save it to Snowflake and try and inference new data from it?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Apologies for the very long message here but I am at my limit of understanding and need some help! I am pretty new to Snowpark and Snowflake in general.

Essentially what I am trying to do is a very standard data science practice. I am taking some data, performing some feature engineering (using one hot and ordinal encoding) and fitting an xgboost model. Once that is done I am saving both the encoders and model into Snowflake via the PUT method. Then I create a udf so that I can inference using the model I have created but this is where my process falls down.

From the error I am seeing it seems that after I have loaded the encoders it is then unable to transform my inferencing data stating the below error:

***"ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"***

This error really confuses me as it seems like it is seeing NANs within the known values but this shouldn't be the case as it has been fit and tested on a specific set of known values!

I have played around with just outputting the known values through the inferencing function but this produces some very strange results where it gives me a list of strings but not comma delimited for example:

['A' 'B' 'C'] - which isn't a construct any language understands from what I know.

So overall my question is, how do I store my encoders and models in Snowflake in order to use them during inferencing???

I will add a basic view of the code I have created so that others can hopefully use it and find the same error -

```
from snowflake.snowpark.session import Session
import snowflake.snowpark.functions as F
import snowflake.connector
import json
import numpy as np
from snowflake.ml.modeling.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder,OrdinalEncoder
from snowflake.ml.modeling.xgboost import XGBRegressor
 
# this connection info is just standard stuff
connection_parameters = json.load(open('connection.json'))
session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
 
mock_df = session.create_dataframe(
    [[979152,"A","XX","SUN","2023-11-24 08:30:00","2023-11-24 12:25:00",189,0.62],
     [987073,"A","ZZ","SUN","2023-12-13 16:15:00","2023-12-13 11:25:00",189,0.75],
     [951384,"C","YY","FAR_SUN","2023-12-05 09:40:00","2023-12-05 13:35:00",189,0.88],
     [952380,"B","WW","FAR_SUN","2023-11-22 19:45:00","2023-11-22 14:30:00",235,0.86],
     [963602,"B","ZZ","FAR_SUN","2023-12-29 10:30:00","2023-12-29 15:05:00",235,0.66]],
    schema=[
        "ID","AIRPORT","A_AIRPORT",
        "CATEGORY","D_DATETIME","A_DATETIME","CAPACITY","TARGET"
    ]
)
 
mock_df = mock_df.select_expr("*","TO_TIMESTAMP(D_DATETIME) AS D_DATETIME_T","TO_TIMESTAMP(A_DATETIME) AS A_DATETIME_T")
 
ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore',input_cols='CATEGORY',output_cols='ROUTE_OHE')
ohe.fit(mock_df)
mock_ohe = ohe.transform(mock_df)
print(ohe.categories_)
 
categories = {
    "AIRPORT": np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])
}
oe = OrdinalEncoder(
    handle_unknown='use_encoded_value',unknown_value=-1,
    encoded_missing_value=-1,input_cols='AIRPORT',
    output_cols='AIRPORT_ENCODE',
    categories=categories
)
oe.fit(mock_ohe)
mock_oe = oe.transform(mock_ohe)
print(oe.categories_)
 
mock_oe = (
    mock_oe
    .withColumn('depart_hour',F.hour(mock_oe.D_DATETIME_T))
    .withColumn('depart_weekday',F.dayofweek(mock_oe.D_DATETIME_T))
    .withColumn('depart_monthday',F.dayofmonth(mock_oe.D_DATETIME_T))
    .withColumn('depart_yearday',F.dayofyear(mock_oe.D_DATETIME_T))
    .withColumn('depart_month',F.month(mock_oe.D_DATETIME_T))
    .withColumn('depart_year',F.year(mock_oe.D_DATETIME_T))
    .withColumn('arrive_hour',F.hour(mock_oe.A_DATETIME_T))
)
 
xgb = XGBRegressor(
    n_estimators = 100,
    max_depth = 3,
    input_cols=[
        "AIRPORT_ENCODE","ROUTE_OHE_FAR_SUN","ROUTE_OHE_SUN",
        "CAPACITY","DEPART_HOUR",
        "DEPART_WEEKDAY","DEPART_MONTHDAY","DEPART_YEARDAY",
        "DEPART_MONTH","DEPART_YEAR","ARRIVE_HOUR"
    ],
    label_cols="TARGET",output_cols="xgb_prediction"
)
 
xgb.fit(mock_oe)
 
 
from joblib import dump
 
def save_object(object_,filename,stagename,auto_compress=True):
 
    dump(object_, filename)
    session.file.put(filename, stagename, overwrite=True,auto_compress=auto_compress)
    return
 
# Extract model object 
xgb_model = xgb.to_xgboost()
ohe_obj = ohe.to_sklearn()
oe_obj = oe.to_sklearn()
 
save_object(xgb_model,'xgb_model.joblib','@AM_TEST_MODELS')
save_object(ohe_obj,'one_hot_encode.joblib','@AM_TEST_MODELS',auto_compress=False)
save_object(oe_obj,'ordinal_encode.joblib','@AM_TEST_MODELS',auto_compress=False)
 
session.add_import("@AM_TEST_MODELS/xgb_model.joblib.gz")
session.add_import("@AM_TEST_MODELS/one_hot_encode.joblib")
session.add_import("@AM_TEST_MODELS/ordinal_encode.joblib")
session.add_packages("pandas==1.5.3","joblib==1.2.0","xgboost==1.7.3","scikit-learn==1.2.2")

##################################
@F.udf(name='predict_target',session=session,replace=True,is_permanent=True,stage_location='@AM_TEST_UDFS')
def predict_target(data: list) -> float:
    import sys
    import pandas as pd
    from joblib import load
    import sklearn
    import xgboost as xgb
    import json
 
    IMPORT_DIRECTORY_NAME = "snowflake_import_directory"
    import_dir = sys._xoptions[IMPORT_DIRECTORY_NAME]
    
    # open up the encoding files
    ohe = load(import_dir + 'one_hot_encode.joblib')
    oe = load(import_dir + 'ordinal_encode.joblib')
    model = load(import_dir + 'xgb_model.joblib.gz')
    print('loaded models')
    
    features = [
        "ID","AIRPORT","A_AIRPORT",
        "CATEGORY","D_DATETIME","A_DATETIME","CAPACITY"
    ]
 
    df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=features)
    print('loaded dataframe')
 
    # transform data for one hot and ordinal encodings
    df_ohe = ohe.transform(df) # ERROR LINE
    df_oe = oe.transform(df_ohe) # ERROR LINE
    print('transformed via one hot and ordinal')
 
    # change date cols to datetime
    df_oe.loc[:,'D_DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(
        df_oe.loc[:,'D_DATETIME'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',yearfirst=True
    )
    df_oe['A_DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(
        df_oe['A_DATETIME'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',yearfirst=True
    )
    print('transformed dates')
 
    df_oe['depart_hour'] = df_oe['D_DATETIME'].dt.hour
    # snowpark function goes from 1-7 whereas pandas goes from 0-6
    df_oe['depart_weekday'] = df_oe['D_DATETIME'].dt.day_of_week + 1
    df_oe['depart_monthday'] = df_oe['D_DATETIME'].dt.day
    df_oe['depart_yearday'] = df_oe['D_DATETIME'].dt.day_of_year
    df_oe['depart_month'] = df_oe['D_DATETIME'].dt.month
    df_oe['depart_year'] = df_oe['D_DATETIME'].dt.year
    df_oe['arrive_hour'] = df_oe['A_DATETIME'].dt.hour
    print('created features')
    
    
    pm = model.predict(df_oe)[0]
    return pm
##################################

inference_df = session.create_dataframe(
    [[979152,"C","ZZ","SUN","2023-11-01 16:30:00","2023-11-01 20:25:00",189],
     [987073,"C","ZZ","SUN","2023-12-18 19:15:00","2023-12-18 22:25:00",189],
     [951384,"A","YY","FAR_SUN","2023-12-06 15:40:00","2023-12-06 17:35:00",189],
     [952380,"A","WW","FAR_SUN","2023-11-22 10:45:00","2023-11-22 14:30:00",235],
     [963602,"B","WW","FAR_SUN","2023-11-30 13:30:00","2023-12-29 15:05:00",235]],
    schema=[
        "ID","AIRPORT","A_AIRPORT",
        "CATEGORY","D_DATETIME","A_DATETIME","CAPACITY"
    ]
)
 
inference_df.select(
    "ID","AIRPORT","A_AIRPORT",
    "CATEGORY","D_DATETIME","A_DATETIME","CAPACITY",
    call_udf('predict_target',
             array_construct(
                 col("ID"),col("AIRPORT"),col("A_AIRPORT"),
                 col("CATEGORY"),col("D_DATETIME"),
                 col("A_DATETIME"),col("CAPACITY")
                )
    ).as_("PREDICTED_TARGET")
).show()
```

Other bits that might be useful to note is:

Snowflake version - 7.44.2

Snowpark for Python version - 1.9.0

Local environment Python version - 3.11 (I CANNOT DOWNGRADE THIS - DONT ASK)

Local environment packages:

pandas - 1.5.3
joblib - 1.2.0
xgboost - 1.7.3
sklearn - 1.2.2
numpy - 1.25.2

If you need any other information then please ask - I am at such a loss here I appreciate any help I can get!

Thanks in advance

Comment: in your function call `inference_df.select` should the array `array_construct`  have the `col`  args, as where is that data coming from?

Comment: Have tried to run it without and see same error. Tbf I don't need the col arguments I have just been following this tutorial and they used them within their inferencing too
 quick start: https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/getting_started_with_dataengineering_ml_using_snowpark_python/index.html?utm_campaign=snowpark-day-20230719-on24&utm_source=on24&utm_medium=referral#5 
code: https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfguide-getting-started-dataengineering-ml-snowpark-python/blob/main/Snowpark_For_Python_ML.ipynb?utm_campaign=snowpark-day-20230719-on24&utm_source=on24&utm_medium=referral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my main issue was a very stupid one and was in fact how I was calling the encoders. I was mistakenly trying to transform the data using the Snowpark API rather than using the scikit-learn API as within my udf I am using a pandas dataframe.
There were a couple of other things incorrect with my code, so things around calling of column names (snowflake changes columns names to be uppercase when storing the table) and random multiindexing of a dataframe but I have fixed those and it looks to be stable now.
One other thing I have changed is the function itself and how I call it, based off some feedback I got from someone at Snowflake. Now the function is utilising their vectorised feature where it is passed a whole dataframe which is processed and passed back rather than being run row wise. This is accompanied by another function that is cached which means we only load the models once during the run.

Full code for the inferencing function can be seen below

```
import cachetools

@cachetools.cached(cache={})
def read_file(filename):
    import sys
    import os
    import joblib
    # Get the "path" of where files added through iport are avalible
    import_dir = sys._xoptions.get("snowflake_import_directory")
    if import_dir:
        with open(os.path.join(import_dir, filename), 'rb') as file:
            m = joblib.load(file)
            return m

session.add_import("@AM_TEST_MODELS/xgb_model.pkl.gz")
session.add_import("@AM_TEST_MODELS/one_hot_encode.pkl")
session.add_import("@AM_TEST_MODELS/ordinal_encode.pkl")
session.add_import("@AM_TEST_MODELS/target_encoding.csv.gz")
session.add_packages("pandas==1.5.3","joblib==1.2.0","xgboost==1.7.3","scikit-learn==1.2.2","cloudpickle==2.2.1","cachetools","snowflake-ml-python")

from snowflake.snowpark.types import PandasDataFrameType,PandasSeriesType,IntegerType,StringType,FloatType,PandasDataFrame,PandasSeries
import pandas as pd


@F.udf(
        name='predict_package_mix_p',session=session,replace=True,
        is_permanent=True,stage_location='@AM_TEST_UDFS',
)
def predict_package_mix_p(
    df:PandasDataFrame[int,str,str,str,str,str,int]
) -> PandasSeries[float]:
    import sys
    import pandas as pd
    from joblib import load
    import sklearn
    import xgboost as xgb
    import json
    import snowflake.ml.modeling

    def transform_simple_target_encode_manual(
            df,transform_col,transform_df
        ):
        df = df.merge(transform_df, on=transform_col)
        return df
    
    def remove_space(df):
        cols = df.columns
        space_cols = [x for x in cols if ' ' in x]
        for c in space_cols:
            new_col = c.replace(" ","_")
            df = df.rename(columns={c:new_col})
        return df

    IMPORT_DIRECTORY_NAME = "snowflake_import_directory"
    import_dir = sys._xoptions[IMPORT_DIRECTORY_NAME]

    ohe = read_file('one_hot_encode.pkl')
    oe = read_file('ordinal_encode.pkl')
    te = pd.read_csv(import_dir + 'target_encoding.csv.gz')
    model = read_file('xgb_model.pkl.gz')
    print('loaded models')
    
    features = [
        "LS1_FLIGHT_ID","DEPARTURE_AIRPORT_CODE","ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_CODE",
        "ROUTE_CATEGORY_NAME","DEPARTURE_DATETIME_LOCAL",
        "ARRIVAL_DATETIME_LOCAL","CAPACITY"
    ]

    df.columns = features
    print('loaded dataframe')

    # transform data for one hot and ordinal encodings
    df_ohe = ohe.transform(df[['ROUTE_CATEGORY_NAME']])
    encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(df_ohe, columns=ohe.categories_)
    encoded_df.columns = encoded_df.columns.get_level_values(0)
    encoded_df = encoded_df.add_prefix('ROUTE_NAME_OHE_')
    df = pd.concat([df, encoded_df], axis=1)
    df['DEPART_CODE_ENCODE'] = oe.transform(df[['DEPARTURE_AIRPORT_CODE']])

    print('transformed via one hot and ordinal')
    # transform using pre-set target encoding
    df_te = transform_simple_target_encode_manual(df,'ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_CODE',te)
    df_final = remove_space(df_te)
    print('transformed via target encode')

    # change date cols to datetime
    df_final.loc[:,'DEPARTURE_DATETIME_LOCAL'] = pd.to_datetime(
        df_final.loc[:,'DEPARTURE_DATETIME_LOCAL'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',yearfirst=True
    )
    df_final['ARRIVAL_DATETIME_LOCAL'] = pd.to_datetime(
        df_final['ARRIVAL_DATETIME_LOCAL'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',yearfirst=True
    )
    print('transformed dates')

    df_final['DEPART_HOUR'] = df_final['DEPARTURE_DATETIME_LOCAL'].dt.hour
    # snowpark function goes from 1-7 whereas pandas goes from 0-6
    df_final['DEPART_WEEKDAY'] = df_final['DEPARTURE_DATETIME_LOCAL'].dt.day_of_week + 1
    df_final['DEPART_MONTHDAY'] = df_final['DEPARTURE_DATETIME_LOCAL'].dt.day
    df_final['DEPART_YEARDAY'] = df_final['DEPARTURE_DATETIME_LOCAL'].dt.day_of_year
    df_final['DEPART_MONTH'] = df_final['DEPARTURE_DATETIME_LOCAL'].dt.month
    df_final['DEPART_YEAR'] = df_final['DEPARTURE_DATETIME_LOCAL'].dt.year
    df_final['ARRIVE_HOUR'] = df_final['ARRIVAL_DATETIME_LOCAL'].dt.hour
    print('created features')

    pm = pd.Series(model.predict(df_final[
            ["DEPART_CODE_ENCODE","ROUTE_NAME_OHE_CITY","ROUTE_NAME_OHE_FAR_SUN",
            "ROUTE_NAME_OHE_SKI","ROUTE_NAME_OHE_SUN","CAPACITY",
            "ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_CODE_ENCODED","DEPART_HOUR",
            "DEPART_WEEKDAY","DEPART_MONTHDAY","DEPART_YEARDAY",
            "DEPART_MONTH","DEPART_YEAR","ARRIVE_HOUR"]
        ]))
    return pm

from snowflake.snowpark.session import Session
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col,array_construct,call_udf
import json
import pandas as pd

# Create Snowflake Session object
connection_parameters = json.load(open('connection.json'))
session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
session.sql_simplifier_enabled = True

test_df = session.create_dataframe(
    [[979152,"LBA","ALC","SUN","2023-11-24 08:30:00","2023-11-24 12:25:00",189],
     [987073,"LBA","FAO","SUN","2023-12-13 16:15:00","2023-12-13 11:25:00",189],
     [951384,"STN","FNC","FAR SUN","2023-12-05 09:40:00","2023-12-05 13:35:00",189],
     [952380,"MAN","LPA","FAR SUN","2023-12-22 19:45:00","2023-12-22 14:30:00",235],
     [963602,"MAN","FUE","FAR SUN","2023-12-29 10:30:00","2023-12-29 15:05:00",235]],
    schema=[
        "LS1_FLIGHT_ID","DEPARTURE_AIRPORT_CODE","ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_CODE",
        "ROUTE_CATEGORY_NAME","DEPARTURE_DATETIME_LOCAL","ARRIVAL_DATETIME_LOCAL","CAPACITY"
    ]
)

test_df.withColumn(
    'PREDICTED_PACKAGE_MIX', 
    predict_package_mix_p([*test_df])).show()
```